# Composer Installation Error

Tags: php-7, magento2.2, magento-community, xdebug

[image]

My php version php 7

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Magento2 goes well with PHP 7.0.2 and 7.2 versions. Dont use PHP 7.1 version. Download XAMPP which is having PHP 7.0.2

Comment: @PavanKumar : Thank You for sharing, but our need php 7.1.10, so how can i install

Answer (score 2):

Check here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html 7.1.x is not at all supported by magento. If your server is having 7.1.x then you have to downdrage ur PHP to PHP 7.0.2 or 7.0.x versions.

[image: Magento2 Technology stack Requirement]

Comment: Wamp logo not changing green color after update PHP 5.5.12 to PHP 7.0.2. how can solve the error?

Comment: could you pls help me : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46967848/8416476

Comment: Do one thing. Forget about wampp. Go for XAMPP. Download xampp from this link https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html. It directly gives PHP 7.0.2. I have downloded the same last day and everything went pretty well with out any breaks.

Comment: may i know which one is secure, Xampp or Wamp?

Comment: There is nothing like that. Both are secured only. This is just a bundle of different softwares. You should consider about the security of PHP's version.